# Preserve parent-child relationships when copying hierarchical data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

We have a table representing a tree of values associated with an entity (call it a project), where the ParentID column refers to the id column of a row's parent. The id column is an auto-incremented IDENTITY column and primary key. Root nodes have a ParentID of 0.

We want to be able to clone the data for a given project and have the resulting ParentIDs refer to the appropriate new ids for the copied values, in a way that meets the restrictions described below the example.

For example, copying the data for ProjectID 611 in the below table:

```
    id      ProjectID    Value         ParentID
--------------------------------------------------
     1      611           Animal        0
     2      611           Frog          1
    13      611           Cow           1
    14      611           Jersey Cow    13
    25      611           Plant         0
    29      611           Tree          25
    31      611           Oak           29
```

Should result in:

```
    id      ProjectID    Value         ParentID
--------------------------------------------------
     1      611           Animal        0
     2      611           Frog          1
    13      611           Cow           1
    14      611           Jersey Cow    13
    25      611           Plant         0
    29      611           Tree          25
    31      611           Oak           29
    32      612           Animal        0
    33      612           Frog          32
    34      612           Cow           32
    35      612           Jersey Cow    34
    36      612           Plant         0
    37      612           Tree          36
    38      612           Oak           37
```

**Restrictions:**

- Solution must work for **SQL Server 2005**. That is, we can't use MERGE (alas).
- We're not comfortable making assumptions about ids or how they compare to ParentIDs; the solution should apply, in principle, to ids/ParentIDs that are uniqueid, for example.
- We'd rather not add an additional column to the table. (My current solution adds an "OldId" column, which the copy procedure sets when copying rows. So I'm currently using a combination of INSERT-SELECT and UPDATE-FROM, joining the OldId column on the ParentID column to get the new id.)  We'd rather not pepper all of our hierarchical tables with OldId columns just to support this copy operation.
- Solution must be reasonably performant; my initial solution was going to be a complicated set of rescursive function calls and loops processing one item at a time. I quickly abandoned that route!

Comment: CTEs are available from SS 2005 onward. Copy the tree using a CTE and an `OUTPUT` clause on the `INSERT` to get a fixup table (temporary or variable) for the id's, then apply the fixups.

Comment: @HABO I was hoping to see how exactly I might do this...I had heard of CTEs but am not sure how I'd use them to solve this problem.

Comment: After pondering using a CTE I realized that it really doesn't help without `MERGE`. I've added an answer that uses one `INSERT` and one `UPDATE`, no loops, and no need to walk through the hierarchies. As such, the performance shouldn't be too bad. The only critical element is that the new hierarchies are in an inconsistent state between the two statements and you need to prevent other users from accessing them, e.g. using a transaction with an isolation level adequate for your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A CTE works nicely with `MERGE`, but is problematic in SQL Server 2005. Sorry for the misleading comment earlier.

The following shows how to clone a project (with multiple trees) and fix up up the parentage to separate the new forest from the old. Note that it does not depend on any particular arrangement of Id's, e.g. they need not be dense, monotonically increasing, ... .

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Projects as Table
  ( Id Int Identity, ProjectId Int, Value VarChar(16), ParentId Int Null );
insert into @Projects ( ProjectId, Value, ParentId ) values
  ( 611, 'Animal', 0 ),
  ( 611, 'Frog', 1 ),
  ( 611, 'Cow', 1 ),
  ( 611, 'Jersey Cow', 3 ),
  ( 611, 'Plant', 0 ),
  ( 611, 'Tree', 5 ),
  ( 611, 'Oak', 6 );
-- Display the raw data.
select * from @Projects;

-- Display the forest.
with IndentedProjects ( Id, ProjectId, Value, ParentId, Level, Path ) as
  ( -- Start with the top level rows.
  select Id, ProjectId, Value, ParentId, 0, Convert( VarChar(1024), Right( '000' + Convert( VarChar(4), Id ), 4 ) )
    from @Projects
    where ParentId = 0
  union all
  -- Add the children one level at a time.
  select P.Id, P.ProjectId, P.Value, P.ParentId, IP.Level + 1, Convert( VarChar(1024), IP.Path + '<' + Right( '000' + Convert( VarChar(4), P.Id ), 4 ) )
    from IndentedProjects as IP inner join
      @Projects as P on P.ParentId = IP.Id
  )
  select Space( Level * 2 ) + Value as [IndentedValue], Id, ProjectId, Value, ParentId, Level, Path
    from IndentedProjects
    order by Path;

-- Clone the project.
declare @OldProjectId as Int = 611;
declare @NewProjectId as Int = 42;
declare @Fixups as Table ( OldId Int, [NewId] Int );
begin transaction -- With suitable isolation since the hierarchy will be invalid until we apply the fixups!
insert into @Projects
  output Inserted.ParentId, Inserted.Id
    into @Fixups
  select @NewProjectId, Value, Id -- Note that we save the old Id in the new ParentId.
    from @Projects as P
    where ProjectId = @OldProjectId;
-- Apply the fixups.
update PNew
  set ParentId = IsNull( FNew.[NewId], 0 )
  -- Output the fixups just to show what is going on.
  output Deleted.Id, Deleted.ParentId as [ParentIdBeforeFixup], Inserted.ParentId as [ParentIdAfterFixup]
  from @Fixups as F inner join
    @Projects as PNew on PNew.Id = F.[NewId] inner join -- Rows we need to fix.
    @Fixups as FOld on FOld.OldId = PNew.ParentId inner join
    @Projects as POld on POld.Id = FOld.OldId left outer join
    @Fixups as FNew on FNew.OldId = POld.ParentId;
commit transaction;

-- Display the forest.
with IndentedProjects ( Id, ProjectId, Value, ParentId, Level, Path ) as
  ( -- Start with the top level rows.
  select Id, ProjectId, Value, ParentId, 0, Convert( VarChar(1024), Right( '000' + Convert( VarChar(4), Id ), 4 ) )
    from @Projects
    where ParentId =0
  union all
  -- Add the children one level at a time.
  select P.Id, P.ProjectId, P.Value, P.ParentId, IP.Level + 1, Convert( VarChar(1024), IP.Path + '<' + Right( '000' + Convert( VarChar(4), P.Id ), 4 ) )
    from IndentedProjects as IP inner join
      @Projects as P on P.ParentId = IP.Id
  )
  select Space( Level * 2 ) + Value as [IndentedValue], Id, ProjectId, Value, ParentId, Level, Path
    from IndentedProjects
    order by Path;
```

Comment: Nice solution. The key is storing the old ID temporarily in the ParentID column! Very clever. Note to CS Profs: This would be a great extra credit problem for DB courses...

Comment: @System.Cats.Lol - Sometimes us old folks have a trick or two up our straitjackets. You can look at it as denormalizing by storing the wrong data in a column, or as a trick to make the column available to the `OUTPUT` clause while overwriting a column that we'll be fixing soon enough. The other key is that your table includes `ProjectId`, so there is no need to walk through the hierarchies to collect up whole trees. Note that the transaction also needs to prevent the view of the original hierarchy from changing since the `UPDATE` uses it in during the fixup. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `ParentID` by adding the `MAX(ID)` to the old `ParentID`.

```
DECLARE @projectID INT
SET @projectID = 611

SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTable ON
BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @maxID INT
SELECT @maxID= MAX(ID) FROM YourTable WITH (UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK)

INSERT INTO YourTable(ID, ProjectID, Value, ParentID)
SELECT
    ID + @maxID,
    ProjectId + 1,
    Value,
    CASE 
        WHEN ParentID > 0 THEN ParentID + @maxID
        ELSE 0
    END
FROM YourTable WITH (UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK)
WHERE
    ProjectID = @projectID

COMMIT TRANSACTION
SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTable OFF
```

You should use a transaction to lock the table. You could also add [locking hints.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213026(SQL.80).aspx)

Comment: I'm wary of adding code that tries to guess the generated id with COUNT...what about concurrency?

Comment: Just make sure you use a transaction.

Comment: OK--but doesn't the select assume that we'll get the rows in the order given in the example?

Comment: What do you mean? Add an `ORDER BY` to specify the order.

Comment: I mean the SELECT in your INSERT-SELECT...it seems to assume that the children get added after their parents. I'm not 100% sure the ParentIDs are necessarily less than child rows' ids in our data. If you've had luck with this sort of "id finagling" in actual practice, I'd be more confident to try it :)

Comment: Why does it matter? The `ParentID` will still be correct regardless of which is inserted first.

Comment: This solution doesn't work if there are gaps in the ids, which is typical; updated the question to make this clearer.

Comment: OK--but now, if the copy of `Frog` gets inserted before the copy of `Animal`, the new `Frog`'s ParentID is incorrect. If we add `ORDER BY id` in the `SELECT` part of your answer, we assume that a row's ParentID is less than its id (otherwise children could end up getting added before parents, resulting in the same bug). This _may_ be a reasonable assumption, but I'm not completely comfortable with it.

Comment: Then turn on `IDENTITY_INSERT` and use `ID + MAX(ID)` as your new `ID`.