# Copying Parent and child attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having issues figuring out the most logical way to clone parent/child product categories for another company.

There can be 3 levels of categories.

ie. `Mens Clothing`(L1) > `Shirt`(L2) > `Short Sleeve`(L3) 
 (`Shirt` is the parent of `Short Sleeve` and `Mens Clothing` is the parent of `Shirt`)

`ParentCategoryId`is the Id of the category directly above. 
`ParentString` is the Id's of all categories above, in order of level.

(ie. for L3 product, it would be the Id for L1 then the Id for L2) 
 
 Table setup is like below.

```
CREATE TABLE #Categories
(
CategoryId INT
,CompanyId INT
,ParentCategoryId INT
,CategoryName VARCHAR(255)
,ParentString VARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO #Categories VALUES
(123, 12, NULL, 'Mens Clothing',     NULL),
(124, 12, 123,  'Shirt',            '123-'),
(125, 12, NULL, 'Womens Clothing',  NULL),
(126, 12, 125,  'Shirt',            '125-'),
(127, 12, 124,  'Short Sleeve',     '123-124-'),
(128, 12, NULL, 'Drinks',           NULL),
(129, 12, 128,  'Water',            '128-')
```

I need to copy all categories and levels over to `CompanyId` 13.

Comment: You might find something of value in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28554667/92546) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is weird solution.

1. We put in CTE all stuff from company 12,
2. We find `MAX` id from this table and then add it to `ROW_NUMBER()`,
3. Convert `ParentString` to XML,
4. Select what we need,

And got output (see below) that can be inserted into `Categories` table:

```
DECLARE @id int 

SELECT @id = MAX(CategoryId) FROM #Categories

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyId ORDER BY CategoryId) + @id as NewCategoryId,
        CategoryId as OldCategoryId,
        CompanyId,
        ParentCategoryId,
        CategoryName,
        CAST('<p>'+REPLACE(STUFF(ParentString,LEN(ParentString),1,''),'-','</p><p>')+'</p>' as xml) parentxml
FROM #Categories
WHERE CompanyId = 12
)

SELECT  c.NewCategoryId,
        13 as CompanyId,
        c1.NewCategoryId as NewParentCategoryId,
        c.CategoryName,
        (
        SELECT CAST(f.NewCategoryId as nvarchar(max)) +'-'
        FROM cte f
        OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT  t.c.value('.','int') as xpart
            FROM c.parentxml.nodes('/p') as t(c)
        ) x
        WHERE OldCategoryId = x.xpart
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ) as ParentString
FROM cte c
LEFT JOIN cte c1 
    ON c1.OldCategoryId = c.ParentCategoryId
```

Output:

```
NewCategoryId   CompanyId   NewParentCategoryId CategoryName    ParentString
130             13          NULL                Mens Clothing   NULL
131             13          130                 Shirt           130-
132             13          NULL                Womens Clothing NULL
133             13          132                 Shirt           132-
134             13          131                 Short Sleeve    130-131-
135             13          NULL                Drinks          NULL
136             13          135                 Water           135-
```

**EDIT**

If `CategoryId` column is an auto-incremented IDENTITY column then better use transaction and turn `IDENTITY_INSERT` ON:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Categories ON
BEGIN TRANSACTION
...
COMMIT TRANSACTION
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Categories OFf
```

Comment: At first glance/test this is looking like it'll work! Will update when I actually get around to running the update. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Add some transaction and identity insert stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, if you wanted to play with XML and global Search and Replace.  In the cteMap2, you'll see that we are very specific as to the replace strings.  Sometimes not necessary, but better safe than sorry.  Just a word of caution, the XML portion is case sensitive as to the field names.

cteMap1 simply creates the standard mapping based on the max value in #Categories (regardless of company)

cteMap2 generates the replace strings, again, very specific to there is no chance of collisions.

Then we simply apply the replaces in one pass

Then we convert the string to xml, which is then converted into a table for consumption (Insert Into ...)

```
Declare @OldCoID int = 12
Declare @NewCoID int = 55

Declare @String varchar(max) = ((Select * from #Categories Where CompanyId=@OldCoID For xml raw))

;with cteMap1 as (
        Select Old  = CategoryID
              ,New  = (Select max(CategoryID) from #Categories) + Row_Number() over (Order By CategoryID)
         From  #Categories
         Where CompanyID = @OldCoID)
    , cteMap2 as (
        Select Old=concat('CategoryId="',Old,'"'),New=concat('CategoryId="',New,'"') From cteMap1
        Union All
        Select Old=concat('ParentCategoryId="',Old,'"'),New=concat('ParentCategoryId="',New,'"') From cteMap1
        Union All
        Select Old=concat('CompanyId="',@OldCoID,'"'),New=concat('CompanyId="',@NewCoID,'"')
        Union All
        Select Old=concat(Old,'-'),New=concat(New,'-') From cteMap1
    )
Select @String = Replace(@String,Old,New) From cteMap2 
Declare @XML xml = @String

Select CategoryId       = xRow.value('@CategoryId[1]','int')
      ,CompanyId        = xRow.value('@CompanyId[1]','int')
      ,ParentCategoryId = xRow.value('@ParentCategoryId[1]','int')
      ,CategoryName     = xRow.value('@CategoryName[1]','varchar(255)')
      ,ParentString     = xRow.value('@ParentString[1]','varchar(20)')
From  @XML.nodes('/row') As A(xRow)
```

Returns

```
CategoryId  CompanyId   ParentCategoryId    CategoryName    ParentString
130         55          NULL                Mens Clothing   NULL
131         55          130                 Shirt           130-
132         55          NULL                Womens Clothing NULL
133         55          132                 Shirt           132-
134         55          131                 Short Sleeve    130-131-
135         55          NULL                Drinks          NULL
136         55          135                 Water           135-
```

Comment: Nice one! Thought of that approach too, but finally used XML only for `ParentString`. +1.

Comment: @gofr1 Thanks.  Some think XML/String manipulation is evil.  Me, not so much.

Answer (score 0):

First shift IDs by max value.

```
declare @shift  int = (select max(CategoryId) from #Categories);
-- data for new company 14 
INSERT  #Categories(
SELECT @shift + CategoryId, 14 companyId, @shift + ParentCategoryId, CategoryName, NULL as ParentString
FROM  #Categories
WHERE companyId = 12;
```

Then recreate ParentString for new company the way you did it for the original company.