# SSIS Parent table Child relation migration

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl

I'm trying to use SSIS to move some data from one SQL server to my Destimation SQL server, the source has a table "Parent" with Identity field ID that is a Foreign key to the "Child" table.

1 - N relation

[image]

The question is simple, what is the best way to transfer the data to a different SQL Server with still a parent child relation.

Note: Both ID (Parent and Child) are identity fields that we do not want to migrate since the destination source wont necessary need to have them.

Please share your comments and ideas.

**FYI**: We create a .Net Code (C#) that does this, we have a query that gets parent data, a query that get childs data and using linq we join the data and we loop parent getting the new ID and inserting as reference of second table. This is working but we want to create the same on SSIS to be able to scale later.

Comment: Here is one quick question. As you mentioned that on destination side id may not be same so what mechanism you are implementing to maintain the parent child relationship between the tables in c# code. This will help SSIS expert to give precise solution.

Comment: You might find something useful in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552101/preserve-parent-child-relationships-when-copying-hierarchical-data/28554667#28554667) answer, Then again, perhaps not. Any question that requests a _best_ solution must provide the appropriate metrics for measuring "bestitude": fewest lines of code, minimized I/O, smallest memory footprint, fastest execution, ... .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have to import Parent Table Before Child Table:**

- First You have to Create Tables On Destination Server, you can achieve this using an query like the following:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_Child](
      [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [Parent_ID] [int] NULL,
      [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_Tbl_Child] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
      [ID] ASC
  )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
  ) ON [PRIMARY]

  GO

  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_Parent](
      [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_Tbl_Parent] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
      [ID] ASC
  )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
  ) ON [PRIMARY]

  GO

  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_Child]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Tbl_Child_Tbl_Parent] FOREIGN KEY([Parent_ID])
  REFERENCES [dbo].[Tbl_Parent] ([ID])
  GO

  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_Child] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Tbl_Child_Tbl_Parent]
  GO
  ```
- Add two OLEDB Connection manager (Source & Destination)

[image]

- Next you have to add a DataFlow Task to Import Parent Table Data From Source. You  have to check `Keep Identity` option

[image]
[image]

- Next you have to add a DataFlow Task to Import Child Table Data From Source. You  have to check `Keep Identity` option

[image]
[image]

- Package May Look like the following

[image]

**WorkAround:** *you can disable constraint and import data then enabling it by adding a SQL Task before and after Importing*

Disable Constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Tbl_Child NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_Tbl_Child_Tbl_Parent
```

Enable Constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Tbl_Child CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_Tbl_Child_Tbl_Parent
```

if using this Workaround it is not necessary to follow an order when importing